# NodeJS: Run module method within sandbox

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, sandbox

I need one simple thing:

```
var Base = function(module){    
    this.outsideMethod = function(arg1)
    {
        // run method in new context - sandbox
        return vm.runInNewContext(module.insideMethod, arg1);
    }
}
```

is something like this possible in nodejs? thx very much

Comment: Does the "insideMethod" function call or use functions/values from outside the context?

Comment: no, that method just process text and object. it should not even use nodejs modules

Comment: Please be more specific then, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: User will have an option to create his own js class (module) which will be imported into our backend system and then executed in chain of other methods. he will be only allowed to use standard js methods + underscore,jquery and some other libs. Its all about data processing. Diagram looks like this:
[ our data (HTML) ] >> [ user methods (sandbox) ] >> [ processing (our side) ] >> [result]

Comment: So you need to sandbox user code on the client side in the browser? In this case, web workers could be what you are searching for. If you need DOM access inside the sandbox though, you could use iframes.

Comment: Sorry, I maybe wrote it wrong, everything is on server side. User just uploads code which he has written in webbrowser editor. our data (html) means we offer html data to be processed by user method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `insideMethod` function does not call or use functions/vlues from outside the context it shall run in, yes.

You can convert any function in Javascript to a string.

Doing `vm.runInNewContext('('+module.insideMethod+')('+JSON.stringify(arg1)+");` could be what you want.